# Grails - DuplicateKeyException

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions

I have got the following piece of code which adds new object to database. Firstly it takes another object from DB and add to the final object.

Few lines of my code

```
            ClassC c = ClassC.findByName(cName)

            ClassD d = new ClassD(
                    name: "WHATEVER",
                    classC: c
            )

            print "AAA\n"

            ClassC.withTransaction {
                c = c.merge()
                // c.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
            }

            print "BBB\n"

            // ClassD.withTransaction {
            //     d = d.merge()
            // }
            // print "CCC\n"

            ClassD.withTransaction {
                d.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
            }

            print "DDD\n"
```

I have got the following error:

```
AAA
BBB

2013-07-31 13:57:14,279 ERROR JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.1 threw an unhandled Exception: 
 org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [xxx.ClassD#15]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [xxx.ClassD#15]
```

Could you help me?

Thanks

---

```
ClassC.withTransaction {
    ClassC c = ClassC.findByName(cName)

    // find the record with name: "WHATEVER" or create a new one if there is none
    ClassD d = ClassD.findOrCreateWhere(name: "WHATEVER")

    c = c.merge()
    c.addToClassesD(d) // static hasMany = [classesD: ClassD] <-- in ClassC domain
    c.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}
```

error goes from line

> c.addToClassesD(d)

:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder$currentRequestAttributes.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   xxx.AuditLogService.getCurrentUser(AuditLogService.groovy:127)    at
>   xxx.AuditLogService$getCurrentUser.callStatic(Unknown Source)     at
>   xxx.AuditLogService$_closure2.doCall(AuditLogService.groovy:58)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>   2013-08-02 09:39:11,110 ERROR ErrorLogger - Job (DEFAULT.1 threw an
>   exception.  org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled
>   exception.    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:224)
>     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder$currentRequestAttributes.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   xxx.AuditLogService.getCurrentUser(AuditLogService.groovy:127)    at
>   xxx.AuditLogService$getCurrentUser.callStatic(Unknown Source)     at
>   xxx.AuditLogService$_closure2.doCall(AuditLogService.groovy:58)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)

Comment: hey, man! can you try the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should do it all inside one transaction only.

As for the error you are getting, I assume you have an `unique` set up for name -- you'll get that error when there is already a record with the name "WHATEVER" already.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
ClassC.withTransaction {
    ClassC c = ClassC.findByName(cName)

    // find the record with name: "WHATEVER" or create a new one if there is none
    ClassD d = ClassD.findOrCreateWhere(name: "WHATEVER")

    c = c.merge()
    d.classC = c
    d.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}
```

Comment: Hi! I just copied a piece of my code. In real code there is no "WHATEVER" but more complex data, so don't worry - it is always unique. The error is from org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException

Comment: Well, that problem occurs when you are initializing a class `new ClassD` with an id or unique property manually, when there is another already in the session. So, you should try to get that entity first (that's what `findOrCreateWhere` does, but if you use an id you need to use `get`) and then use the instance found or create a new one for the update.

Comment: Hi, I read your hints and I updaed my post. Now, I have got another error. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AuditLogService. It seems you are implementing some sort of auditing or security on domain classes (or Hibernate) and this requires a security context, while you are calling this code outside one.

Also, just out of curiosity, why are you calling .merge() on c?